# How to pack a module of a scala multi-project with sbt-pack

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to pack modules of a multi project, but th jar generated for each modules is empty (only the manifest is present) and there is no script generated in the folder build. My project is organized around a main module called core that has a lot of common code (a kind of lib). The other modules depend of the module core. I guess I don't organized the modules correctly. You can find the build.sbt that i use:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "0.1.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
  crossPaths := false
)

lazy val core = (project in file("."))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(blabla))

lazy val module1 = project
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .dependsOn(core)
  .settings(packAutoSettings)

lazy val module2 = project
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .dependsOn(core)
  .settings(packAutoSettings)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already figured this out. But for the benefit of any future viewers, use `.settings(packAutoSettings: _*)` instead of `.settings(packAutoSettings)`